# Django OperationalError

Tags: django, база-данных, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework

Есть сайт на Django. Загрузили на хостинг. Бэк работает окремо от фронта по АПИ. При обращении сайта к АПИ Джанго - выскакивает ошибка:

> could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure
> in name resolution

Что не так с БД?
Второй день сижу, не могу разобраться. Понял только, что Докеру что-то не нравится в БД.
Хелпаните, а?)

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: avihovalot.redis
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    command: redis-server --maxmemory 512mb --maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru --appendonly yes
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  django:
    container_name: 'avihovalot.django'
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - 9000:8001
      - 8001:8001

    restart: always

    # command: python -m uvicorn crm_transfer.asgi:application --reload --timeout-keep-alive 0 --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8001 --loop=uvloop
    command: /usr/bin/supervisord --configuration /app/supervisord.conf

    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
      - postgres

    volumes:
      - .:/app

    working_dir: /app/

  daphne:
    container_name: 'avihovalot.daphne'
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - 8008:8008
    depends_on:
      - django
    working_dir: /app/
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8008 crm_transfer.asgi:application

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    container_name: "avihovalot.postgres"
    volumes:
      - avihovalot_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init_db.sql:/app/init_db.sql
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "54330:5433"

volumes:
  static: { }
  media: { }
  redis: { }
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
  avihovalot_postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++ cmake clang python3-dev python-dev python3-pip nano \
    bpython3 postgresql libgmp10-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev ca-certificates supervisor

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install setuptools cython
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install uvicorn[standard] websockets
RUN python -m pip install pgcli
#RUN daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8008 crm_transfer.asgi:channel_layer
USER root
EXPOSE 9000 8008 8001
```

Comment: покажите файлы settings.py и docker-compose.yml

Comment: Есть, добавил в вопрос

Comment: API в сервисе daphne? Если да, то там не хватает секции ` links:` с postgres.

Comment: Покажите еще `Dockerfile`, не видно как получают значения `POSTGRES_DB` и т.п.

Comment: Есть и Dockerfile

Comment: POSTGRES_DB получают значения из .env

Comment: а какое значение берется из env для POSTGRES_HOST? могу предположить, что это 'postgres', но оно должно быть `avihovalot.postgres` судя по docker-compose. Поменяйте значение в енвах на 'avihovalot.postgres' и должно сработать

Comment: Окей, понял, пойду попробую.
Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Фурычит! 
Спасибо Roman Konoval!
Огромнейшее спасибо Ersain!)